# Como agrupar valores de um json

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho um JSON parecido com esse:

```
[
    {
        "id": 459,
        "razao_social": "Testosvaldo de Testousa",
        "cidade": "Testolandia",
    },
    {
        "id": 472,
        "razao_social": "teste trr",
        "cidade": "Belo Horizonte",
    },
    {
        "id": 473,
        "razao_social": "teste trr",
        "cidade": "Belo Horizonte",
    }
]
```

Como faço para retornar um JSON agrupado por cidade?

Comment: Pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserializing-a-json-into-a-javascript-object

Comment: Qual o resultado que espera?

Comment: Seria a última resposta dessa pergunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961446/group-by-for-json-data-using-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode criar um novo objeto, navegar pelo `json` usando um `for`, e adicionar um novo nó para cada cidade, e ir agrupando as cidades dentro desse nó, assim:

```js
var jsData=[
    {
        "id": 459,
        "razao_social": "Testosvaldo de Testousa",
        "cidade": "Testolandia",
    },
    {
        "id": 472,
        "razao_social": "teste trr",
        "cidade": "Belo Horizonte",
    },
    {
        "id": 473,
        "razao_social": "teste trr",
        "cidade": "Belo Horizonte",
    }
];


var agrupadoPorCidade = {};
for (var key in jsData) {
    var cidade = jsData[key].cidade;  
    if (!agrupadoPorCidade[cidade]) {
        agrupadoPorCidade[cidade] = [];
    }
    agrupadoPorCidade[cidade].push(jsData[key]);
}

console.log(agrupadoPorCidade);
```